# Emissão e controle de arquivo de registro de licença de software

Tags: c#, .net, licença

Tenho um sistema para controlar e emitir arquivos de registro de licenças eletrônicas, para eu ter o controle de quantas máquinas meu software poderá ser executado. Meu professor me aconselhou a usar o [CPUID](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpuid) do processador para validar e gerar um arquivo de licença (obter o `CPUID` e fazer um calculo em cima dele, assim o resultado seria exclusivo para cada processador) e a validação seria efetuada no momento da instalação, as requisições seria feita para o servidor que ia solicitar o `CPUID` da maquina e retornar o arquivo de licença.

Há outras maneiras de fazer este controle de registro de licença? Existe alguma API ou recurso? E como a implementação pode ser feita?

Aqui segue meu protótipo básico que obtém o `CPUID` e executa um cálculo. São duas funções `string getCPUID()` e `double CalculaCpuId(string cpuid)` é a base para gerar o arquivo de registro de licença eletrônica.

Função `getCPUID`:

```
private string getCPUID()
{
    String cpuid = "";
    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select ProcessorID From Win32_processor");
        ManagementObjectCollection mbsList = mbs.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList)
        {
            cpuid = mo["ProcessorID"].ToString();
        }

        return cpuid;
    }
    catch (Exception) { return cpuid; }
}
```

Função `CalculaCpuId`:

```
private double CalculaCpuId(string cpuid) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpuid))
        return 0;

    double resultado = 0;
    int soma = 0;
    string digito;

    for (int i = 0; i < cpuid.Length; i++)
    {
        digito = cpuid[i].ToString();
        soma += Convert.ToInt32(digito, 16);
    }

    resultado = (soma / ((Math.Pow(2, 2)) + 4));

    return resultado;
}
```

Estou usando o Visual Studio para desenvolver meu sistema que precisa do controle de registro de licença.

Comment: Um método simples que já utilizei com sucesso para limitar as máquinas que podem rodar um software é o *"hardlock"* (dá uma googlada). Outros métodos que usei envolvem o uso de um servidor gerenciador de licenças - local na rede do cliente ou na nuvem (dependendo das restrições do ambiente do cliente); ou um simples contador de acessos  simultâneos no servidor de aplicativos do sistema (se houver um servidor de aplicativos; além disso, se o servidor permitir *farm*, há que se preocupar com a contagem centralizada de acessos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pegar o ID do processador não é solução, esta informação pode nem estar disponível. E isto sequer foi feito para identificar qual é o processador individual. Qualquer solução tentando identificar a máquina tem potencial de falhar.

Uma que usam e costuma funcionar melhor em algumas situações é [pegar o número serial do disco](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Está longe de ser uma solução perfeita, pelo contrário, ela tem seus próprios defeitos. Não gosto muito do WMI mas se quiser continuar usando procure pelo [`DeviceID`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Existem softwares prontos que podem fazer isto por você.

Comment: Neste caso para implementar seria a mesma logica minha, pegar o numero do serial do disco e verificar com o servidor no momento da instalação do software, e apos a instalação sempre que o software iniciar e iria refazer o calculo gerar o numero de licença e vê se bate com o numero que foi gerado pela primeira vez que foi tratado no servido, isso?

Comment: Sim, até que algo dê errado. Se está pensando em proteger o software, isto não resolve muito a não ser pra quem só quer piratear se não tiver nada protegendo. Se software não vale a pena, ninguém vai piratear. Se ele valer, dá-se um jeito mesmo com esta medida.

Comment: Quero evitar que ele seja copiado msm. Tipo, se o cliente comprou para usar em duas maquinas, ele tera que comprar outra licença para usar numa terceira maquina, para que ele não instale o software em um monte de maquina.

Comment: Não sou advogado, mas já adianto, isto é ilegal.

Comment: O que vc sugere, para fazer o controle, tipo como deve ser feito, ou como é feito?

Comment: Não sabia que isto é ilegal, ja testemunhei muitas empresas usar este modelo, pensei que fazia parte do contrato do software.

Comment: Controle é uma coisa, proibir a pessoa de instalar onde ela quiser é outra coisa. A única vez que vi algo do tipo descrito no comentário foi a Microsoft, e parou de fazer rapidinho. Fora isto pode ter umas empresas desavisadas e desconhecidas. A minha sugestão é não se preocupar com isto. A pirataria não costuma ocorrer como a pessoa acha que vai ocorrer.